# Prove $ xy+yz+zx \geq 9xyz $

Tags: inequality

If $x,y,z>0$ and $x+y+z=1$, prove $ xy+yz+zx \geq 9xyz $.

Can anyone help me? I think I'm close, but I can't get to the end.
Using geometric and arithmetic inequality, I got $(xy+yz+xz)(2+xyz) \geq 9xyz$.

Thank you

Comment: It might be helpful for others if you explained in more detail how you got as far as you did.

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$xy+yz+zx \geq 9xyz \iff \frac1x+ \frac1y+\frac1z\ge 9$$

and by [**HM-AM inequality**](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality)

$$\frac3{\frac1x+ \frac1y+\frac1z}\le \frac{x+y+z}3$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,
$$
\begin{aligned}
xy+yz+zx
&=
(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)
\\
&\ge 3(x\cdot y\cdot z)^{1/3}\cdot 3(xy\cdot yz\cdot zx)^{1/3}
\\
&=9xyz\ .
\end{aligned}
$$